# MS Word function to append a Range to a document

Tags: vba, delphi, ms-word

Suppose I want to add some text at the end of a document and immediately access
it as a `Range` object so I can set some properties of it **without** affecting the preceding text.  Ideally, the `Range.InsertAfter`
method would return a Range object which would be perfect for this, but it doesn't.

It irks me that Word must know perfectly well what range defines the result of calling `InsertAfter`, but on the face of it, I need to calculate it "after the fact" from the length of the inserted text, or in some other way.

So I've devised a simple-minded work-around.  In pseudo-code (actually it's Delphi
code but I hope that won't discourage VBA answers) what I do is this

```
ARange := Document.Range
ARange.Text := 'AAA'

AEnd := ARange.End - 1        // AEnd is an integer
ARange.SetRange(AEnd, AEnd)
ARange.Text := 'XXX'
ARange.Bold := True
```

and it seems that I can carry on indefinitely adding blocks of text to the end
of a document by repeating the second block of code.

The line

```
ARange.SetRange(AEnd, AEnd)
```

as I understand it, seems to construct a new Range at the end of the existing one (unlike calling Collapse on an existing range),
and works fine for the simple test cases I've tried.  But it leaves me wondering
whether I'm missing a trick somewhere.  Is there a more direct way to append a range
to a document and get a reference to it?

PS: I should have been a bit clearer that I'm trying to do this without using the Selection object (for a variety of reasons, including the fact that you can only have one of them at at time).

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite.  I should have mentioned that I was trying to avoid using Selection because of a recent comment here by Cindy Meister (who seems to be a hardcore Word specialist and expert).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various ways to get the Range at the end of the document. You've discovered one, but as you say, it's somewhat circuitous. My preference:

```
Word.Range rngEndOfDoc = Document.Content; 
//Content returns a Range object and is a property, not a method like Range()
rngEndOfDoc.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
rngEndOfDoc.Text = "Text at the end of the document";
```

*Collapsing* the Range is conceptually like pressing the Right (or Left) arrow key when you have a selection. So rngEndOfDoc becomes a "point" rather than containing the entire content of the main body of the document.

FWIW I can never think of a situation when I'd use EndKey for this (emulate user actions) and I'd only change the Selection when I want to leave the user at the end of the document so that he can start typing at that location.

Comment: When developing in  Delphi, it's automating the document itself. The user is not present; this isn't a VBA macro that the user will run from within  Word. It's fine to move the selection in a document you're creating programmatically, and it's fine to use EndKey.

Comment: @KenWhite. Not really, no, it isn't. For one thing, it's not as effiicient as working with a Range. Even if the user isn't interacting with the document, Word is having to change where the cursor is in the document. And if the Document window is not visible, Selection can be tricky since Word does rely on "physically" laying out the page for certain things. Selection is inherently unpredictable, although I grant in the case of EndKey for the current Story you probably will end up where you expect. But if there are alternatives to using Selection, you should avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: That's your preference. Using Selection is easy, and it's quick enough for most needs. I use it to automate some document generation and it's performant enough for my needs. If you have another preference, that's your choice; it doesn't make using it wrong.

Comment: @CindyMeister:  Thanks, I'm glad my q caught your attention, because I was following up on that comment you made on an answer of mine recently.  When I saw your code, I was expecting that calling .Bold := True immediately afterwards would result on the entire text, including the text above the insertion becoming bold, because that's what my previous experiment led me to expect.  But maybe I got in a muddle, because using your code only the inserted bit is bolded.  I will back-track, and try to see where my muddle arose.

Comment: Btw, I have upvoted all three answers, but I'm accepting this one because it  is closest to where I started from.  I still wish InsertAfter/InsertBefore returned a range, though ;=)

Comment: @MartynA Ping me in a comment on that question if something's not clear :-) RE InsertAfter/InsertBefore: debatable. I can see the logic of including it as part of an existing Range and if I didn't want that, but did want to retain the original range: use a different Range object, set to Duplicate of the original, Collapse, then InsertAfter/InsertBefore and the duped Range should contain the new info.

Comment: An example of where the Selection.EndKey and Range.Collapse methods differ is when the last section of the document is protected for forms. Then, the Range & Collapse approach correctly identifies the end of the document (leaving aside footers/footnotes/endnotes) but insertion at that point results in a trappable error. The EndKey approach can behave differently depending on what is in the document and what is protected. So as usual, a lot depends on whether the specification is, e.g. "I know enough about the document to know that I don't have to consider that" or otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

With thanks for the three admirable answers from others, I thought I would add my
own.  The following are two versions of the function that I started out wishing Word provided
natively, returning an appended range.

The first version uses the MS Word objects in the MS Word Type Library import
unit that traditionally comes with Delphi (e.g. the Word2000.Pas one), and uses "early binding" automation,
while the second version does the same thing using late binding.

```
function AppendRange(InputRange : Range) : Range;
var
  Direction : OleVariant;
begin
  Result := InputRange;
  Direction := wdCollapseEnd;
  Result.Collapse(Direction);
end;

function AppendRangeLB(InputRange : OleVariant) : OleVariant;
begin
  Result := InputRange;
  Result.Collapse(wdCollapseEnd);
end;
```

Usage is e.g.

```
AppendedRange := AppendRange(ExistingRange);
AppendedRange.Text := 'YYY';
```

Comment: You know, this would be a valuable contribution, on its own. StackOverflow allows you to post a question and answer it, yourself, as a contribution to the Q&A concept of the site. It might make more sense to ask the specific question and post the above as its answer, and mark it as the answer :-)

Comment: @CindyMeister:  Thanks for that, though I'm a bit nervous that answering your own questions is a bit like talking to yourself being the first sign of ...  Seriously, though, I'll maybe give that a try with a slightly more sophisticated version of my answer using (if I can get it to work, which will be an interesting little project in itself) a language feature added to Delphi a while back.  I'll ping you if/when done.

Answer (score 2):

Think of the `Document.Range` as the union of all the possible ranges in the main document (i.e. apart from headings, footers, floating stuff etc.). It always starts before the first character and ends after the last character (that, in my experience, is always a hidden paragraph mark). It is not possible to define another range that is after the current `Document.Range` or, conceptually "append" anything after `Document.Range`, because there is no "after" the `Document.Range` (it always reaches to the end).

Thus, to extend a document with new text or other inline objects, you have to insert them at the end of the `Document.Range` - actually just before the end, as that last, hidden, paragraph mark must still be the final character of the document. This is just what you are doing in your pseudocode.
In VBA, an empty range at the end of the document can be referenced with

```
Document.Range(Document.Range.End-1, Document.Range.End-1)
```

Attempting to define it at `Document.Range.End` actually raises an error, as it points to after that last (hidden) character - and that is out of the Document - that is why we need the "-1".

After getting this range we may fill it with stuff - expanding it and, logically, the `Document.Range`. For example, to add text at the end of the active document, one would write

```
ActiveDocument.Range(ActiveDocument.Range.End-1, ActiveDocument.Range.End-1).Text = "New Text"
```

Notice that the same "final" empty range can be reached with:

```
Document.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range
```

Comment: Thanks:  " because there is no "after" the Document.Range".  Yes, good point, +1.  "Attempting to define it at Document.Range.End":  Odd, because it works for me, let me try .End - 1 in my code ...

Comment: Oh, got this one... That's because you use `Range.SetRange`. This method automatically caps the value of its parameters to `Range.End - 1` and does not generate any error. If you do `ARange.SetRange AEnd+100, AEnd+100` it will still set your range - silently - to (AEnd-1, AEnd-1) - and will hide the fact that you actually pointed to an invalid position. The `Document.Range` on the other hand will throw an error.

Comment: Aha, nice catch1.  Could you clarify, please, exactly what you mean by "The Document.Range on the other hand "?  I.e. what code exactly will throw the error you mention.

Comment: I meant the Document.Range(start, end) method/property that I used in the answer. Sorry.

Comment: set ARange = Document.Range(AEnd, AEnd)  will throw an error

Comment: Thanks ever so much with that about Document.Range().  It explains something I found very confusing in an MS Word textbook, namely something which implied (but didn't show how, or to what purpose) Document.Range can be called with parameters, which was not what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in Word 15 (Office 365) using the Word 2010 type library (I'm using early binding, but it should work the same with late binding as well). `Word` is a `TWordApplication`, and `aRange` is a `WordRange`.

```
Word.Selection.EndKey(wdStory, wdMove);
aRange := Word.Selection.Range;
aRange.Text := 'This is new text added at the end.';
```